# Why can't I draw two lines of varying colors in my HTML5 canvas?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I am trying to use HTML5 canvas to draw a red line to the left of a green line. Here is my javascript:

```
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.height = 150;
canvas.width = 150;
var canvasContext = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvasContext.beginPath();

// Draw the red line.
canvasContext.strokeStyle = '#f00';
canvasContext.moveTo(10, 0);
canvasContext.lineTo(10, 100);
canvasContext.stroke();

// Draw the green line.
canvasContext.moveTo(50, 0);
canvasContext.strokeStyle = '#0f0';
canvasContext.lineTo(50, 100);
canvasContext.stroke();

document.body.appendChild(canvas);​
```

However, in Google Chrome, I get a dark green line to the left of a light green line. Why? I called stroke twice right? Hence, why should my first stroke affect my second one?

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/AhdJr/) is a JSFiddle that illustrates what I mean.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You aren't calling `canvasContext.beginPath();` when you start drawing your second line.

To make the drawing sections more independent, I added whitespace:

```
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.height = 150;
canvas.width = 150;

var canvasContext = canvas.getContext('2d');

// Draw the red line.
canvasContext.beginPath();
canvasContext.strokeStyle = '#f00';
canvasContext.moveTo(10, 0);
canvasContext.lineTo(10, 100);
canvasContext.stroke();

// Draw the green line.
canvasContext.beginPath();
canvasContext.moveTo(50, 0);
canvasContext.strokeStyle = '#0f0';
canvasContext.lineTo(50, 100);
canvasContext.stroke();

document.body.appendChild(canvas);
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AhdJr/2/**

Comment: Thanks, if that's the case, I have a 2nd question: Why is the line to the left darker than the other one? I didn't set an opacity value for either line, so why did canvas blend the colors?

Comment: I honestly have no idea. Looking at the [documentation](http://dev.w3.org/html5/2dcontext/#dom-context-2d-beginpath), it seems like `beginPath()` clears subpaths, so possibly the second line is (somehow) a combination of the previous one and the current one.

Comment: I think its because you drew it twice, if you remove the initial stroke, they'll both be the same colors, though this still strange, I don't think the frame buffers are being cleared, when you call stroke multiple times, or something to do with the default opacity.

Comment: The two lines have 0.5 opacity because they're 1px wide but its being drawn as 2px wide because they're drawn on whole numbered x values. The first line is drawn twice (like Samy said 5 years ago) and the second line is only drawn once. The first line's opacity becomes 1.0 when its drawn for the second time, but the second line remains 0.5. If you move both lines over by half a pixel then they're the same color: https://jsfiddle.net/jbrundage372/5d9tazew/

Answer (score 7):

very interesting as far as I can tell the way webgl or opengl work is like a large state machine, where you define a state, draw, update the state draw again, and so on ...

Though Im not sure if canvas follows the same principles even if its just meant for simple 2d renderings.

I managed to ge it working simply beginning a new path.

```
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.height = 150;
canvas.width = 150;
var canvasContext = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvasContext.beginPath();

// Draw the red line.

canvasContext.moveTo(10, 0);
canvasContext.lineTo(10, 100);
canvasContext.strokeStyle = '#FF0000';
canvasContext.stroke();

canvasContext.beginPath(); // begin new path
// Draw the green line.
canvasContext.moveTo(50, 0);
canvasContext.strokeStyle = '#00FF00';
canvasContext.lineTo(50, 100);
canvasContext.stroke();

document.body.appendChild(canvas);​
```

I have limited experience with webgl so if Im mistaken please correct me.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the Canvas element and WebGL are different things.

Comment: @Blender yeah I think their implement differently Im not sure if canvas follows the same principles that *gl follow, it just look like it from the example codes when compared to opengl, you know like getting the context setting the color and such, so I can't really be too sure, thanks.