# How to color line in canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

EDIT: I'm trying to get a *single* line colored, not the whole grid

So, what I'm trying to do is that when the canvas gets clicked, the lines selected move and get colored.

I already have the lines moving but I cannot [get them colored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11895807/why-cant-i-draw-two-lines-of-varying-colors-in-my-html5-canvas). I know I have to use the `strokeStyle` property, but how do I get the specific line colored?

I tried putting the `strokeStyle` under the `draw_each` method, but that doesn't work, and I don't know why. Here's my code:

```
  //draw each line in array
function draw_each(p1, p2, p3, p4) {

    $.moveTo(p1.x, p1.y);
    $.lineTo(p2.x, p2.y);
    $.moveTo(p1.x, p1.y);
    $.lineTo(p4.x, p4.y);

    if (p1.ind_x == gnum - 2) {
      $.moveTo(p3.x, p3.y);
      $.lineTo(p4.x, p4.y);
    }
    if (p1.ind_y == gnum - 2) {
      $.moveTo(p3.x, p3.y);
      $.lineTo(p2.x, p2.y);
    }
  }
```

https://codepen.io/diazabdulm/pen/qJyrZP?editors=0010

Comment: But what is wrong with using `strokeStyle`

Comment: Are you trying to colour all the lines or just one line? Your code is currently working for me.

Comment: ctx.beginPath(); strokeStyle = color; And then do your stuff like drawing lines

Comment: This is unclear what you are asking. On click, **all** the lines are affected by the wave effect. So there is no "*specific line*". For a color effect to be added on there, I could see a general gradient, but stroking a single line makes no sense. Also, are you the author of this code?

Comment: @XTOTHEL I'm trying to get one line colored

Comment: @Kaiido I want to do a general gradient but I don't know how to select the lines for such a thing. Do you need to select lines or create a rectangle?

Comment: Please describe more precisely what you are after. Are you trying to apply color based on the force each node received? In that case that's not a single line, but every segment. [(Like here)](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZqMvbE)

Comment: @Kaiido apologies for not being clear enough, what I wanted to do was color a single line based on click and use a gradient so it looks like a gradient coming off of the mouse. It's like your pen. Should I use `createRadialGradient()` on the canvas? How is that different from your pen?

Comment: I'll compose an answer based on my pen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that what you want is actually to generate a color per segment based on the force that's been applied to it, so that the wave effect keeps its effect.

What you can do, is to save the median of each node's velocity in both axis as a mean to represent the force they're currently experiencing, and in your drawing part to get the median of all nodes that will compose each segment of your grid and compose a color from it.

But this comes with a drawback: your code was well written enough to compose the whole grid a single sub-path, thus limiting the number of drawings necessary. But now, we have to make each segment its own sub-path (since they'll got their own color), so we'll loose a lot in terms of performances...

```js
var gnum = 90; //num grids / frame
var _x = 2265; //x width (canvas width)
var _y = 1465; //y height (canvas height)
var w = _x / gnum; //grid sq width
var h = _y / gnum; //grid sq height
var $; //context
var parts; //particles 
var frm = 0; //value from
var P1 = 0.0005; //point one
var P2 = 0.01; //point two
var n = 0.98; //n value for later
var n_vel = 0.03; //velocity
var ŭ = 0; //color update
var msX = 0; //mouse x
var msY = 0; //mouse y
var msdn = false; //mouse down flag

var Part = function() {
  this.x = 0; //x pos
  this.y = 0; //y pos
  this.vx = 0; //velocity x
  this.vy = 0; //velocity y
  this.ind_x = 0; //index x
  this.ind_y = 0; //index y
};

Part.prototype.frame = function() {

  if (this.ind_x == 0 || this.ind_x == gnum - 1 || this.ind_y == 0 || this.ind_y == gnum - 1) {
    return;
  }

  var ax = 0; //angle x
  var ay = 0; //angle y
  //off_dx, off_dy = offset distance x, y
  var off_dx = this.ind_x * w - this.x;
  var off_dy = this.ind_y * h - this.y;
  ax = P1 * off_dx;
  ay = P1 * off_dy;

  ax -= P2 * (this.x - parts[this.ind_x - 1][this.ind_y].x);
  ay -= P2 * (this.y - parts[this.ind_x - 1][this.ind_y].y);

  ax -= P2 * (this.x - parts[this.ind_x + 1][this.ind_y].x);
  ay -= P2 * (this.y - parts[this.ind_x + 1][this.ind_y].y);

  ax -= P2 * (this.x - parts[this.ind_x][this.ind_y - 1].x);
  ay -= P2 * (this.y - parts[this.ind_x][this.ind_y - 1].y);

  ax -= P2 * (this.x - parts[this.ind_x][this.ind_y + 1].x);
  ay -= P2 * (this.y - parts[this.ind_x][this.ind_y + 1].y);

  this.vx += (ax - this.vx * n_vel);
  this.vy += (ay - this.vy * n_vel);
//EDIT\\
// store the current velocity (here base on 100 since it will be used with hsl())
  this.color = (Math.abs(this.vx)+Math.abs(this.vy)) * 50;


  this.x += this.vx * n;
  this.y += this.vy * n;
  if (msdn) {
    var dx = this.x - msX;
    var dy = this.y - msY;
    var ɋ = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
    if (ɋ > 50) {
      ɋ = ɋ < 10 ? 10 : ɋ;
      this.x -= dx / ɋ * 5;
      this.y -= dy / ɋ * 5;
    }
  }
  
};

function go() {
    parts = []; //particle array
    for (var i = 0; i < gnum; i++) {
      parts.push([]);
      for (var j = 0; j < gnum; j++) {
        var p = new Part();
        p.ind_x = i;
        p.ind_y = j;
        p.x = i * w;
        p.y = j * h;
        parts[i][j] = p;
      }
    }
  }
  //move particles function
function mv_part() {
    for (var i = 0; i < gnum; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < gnum; j++) {
        var p = parts[i][j];
        p.frame();
      }
    }
  }
  //draw grid function
function draw() {
//EDIT
// we unfortunately have to break the drawing part
// since each segment has its own color, we can't have a single sub-path anymore...
    ŭ -= .5;
    for (var i = 0; i < gnum - 1; i += 1) {
      for (var j = 0; j < gnum - 1; j += 1) {
        var p1 = parts[i][j];
        var p2 = parts[i][j + 1];
        var p3 = parts[i + 1][j + 1];
        var p4 = parts[i + 1][j];
        draw_each(p1, p2, p3, p4);
      }
    }

  }
  //draw each in array
function draw_each(p1, p2, p3, p4) {
    // for each segment we set the color
    $.strokeStyle = `hsl(0deg, ${(p1.color+p2.color+p3.color+p4.color) / 4}%, 50%)`;
    // begin a new sub-path
    $.beginPath();
    $.moveTo(p1.x, p1.y);
    $.lineTo(p2.x, p2.y);
    $.moveTo(p1.x, p1.y);
    $.lineTo(p4.x, p4.y);

    if (p1.ind_x == gnum - 2) {
      $.moveTo(p3.x, p3.y);
      $.lineTo(p4.x, p4.y);
    }
    if (p1.ind_y == gnum - 2) {
      $.moveTo(p3.x, p3.y);
      $.lineTo(p2.x, p2.y);
    }
    // and stroke it
    $.stroke();
  }
  //call functions to run
function calls() {
    $.fillStyle = "hsla(0, 0%, 7%, 1)";
    $.fillRect(0, 0, _x, _y);

    mv_part();
    draw();
    frm++;
  }

var c = document.getElementById('canv');
var $ = c.getContext('2d');
$.fillStyle = "hsla(0, 0%, 7%, 1)";
$.fillRect(0, 0, _x, _y);

function resize() {
  if (c.width < window.innerWidth) {
    c.width = window.innerWidth;
  }

  if (c.height < window.innerHeight) {
    c.height = window.innerHeight;
  }
}
requestAnimationFrame(go);

document.addEventListener('click', MSMV, false);
document.addEventListener('click', MSDN, false);

function MSDN(e) {
  msdn = true;
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    msdn = false;
  }, 100);
}

function MSUP(e) {
  msdn = false;
}

function MSMV(e) {
  var rect = e.target.getBoundingClientRect();
  msX = e.clientX - rect.left;
  msY = e.clientY - rect.top;
}

window.onload = function() {
  run();

  function run() {
    requestAnimationFrame(calls);
    requestAnimationFrame(run);
  }
  resize();
};
onresize = resize;
```

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor:move;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canv" width="150" height="150"></canvas>
```

Now, a more performant way, but less good looking, would be to draw a radial-gradient where the click happened, with a bit of compositing, you'd be able to get something cheap that might work, but it would be quite a lot of coding actually to get multiple such gradients at the same time...

Comment: Thank you. I really appreciate your response. Do you have any documentation where I can learn more about force nodes in HTML canvas?

Answer (score 0):

That works for me:

```
  //draw each line in array
function draw_each(p1, p2, p3, p4) {

    $.moveTo(p1.x, p1.y);
    $.lineTo(p2.x, p2.y);
    $.moveTo(p1.x, p1.y);
    $.lineTo(p4.x, p4.y);

    if (p1.ind_x == gnum - 2) {
      $.moveTo(p3.x, p3.y);
      $.lineTo(p4.x, p4.y);
    }
    if (p1.ind_y == gnum - 2) {
      $.moveTo(p3.x, p3.y);
      $.lineTo(p2.x, p2.y);
    }

    $.strokeStyle = '#458920';
  }
```

Comment: @rv7 Whoops, my bad

Comment: No need to set it in the loop. Setting it once at the begin of `draw` lik it is currently is enough.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention, I'm trying to get a single line colored. Not the whole grid